# Merge 2 dictionaries, and try to update the sum if there is common keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, and I need to combine them.
But if a key is in both dictionaries, the new value must be the sum of the previous two.
That is what I tried:

```
dict1 = {
    "Elizabeth Alexandra Mary": 250000,
    "Barack Hussein Obama II": 1750000,
    "Zhang Aiqin": 1000,
    "Dean Craig Pelton": 1000000,
    }

dict2 = {
    "Christopher Larkin": 50000,
    "Eyal Shani": 5000,
    "Dean Craig Pelton": 2500000,
    "Sheldon Cooper": 15600000
    }

dict1.update(dict2)
print('Updated dictionary:')
print(dict1)
```

But the value of Dean Craig Pelton is 2500000 and not 3500000 as I wanted.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other suggestions will work.  But if you want to try this more Pythonic way:    (or *just being lazy .*.. ;-)

```
from collections import Counter

d3 = Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2)

print(d3)           # to confirm it
```

> **Output:**

```
Counter({'Sheldon Cooper': 15600000, 'Dean Craig Pelton': 3500000, 'Barack Hussein Obama II': 1750000, 'Elizabeth Alexandra Mary': 250000, 'Christopher Larkin': 50000, 'Eyal Shani': 5000, 'Zhang Aiqin': 1000})
```

Comment: Nice alternative. And very clear. +1

Comment: Here is a good article for it - https://realpython.com/python-counter/

Answer (score 2):

You could also use get() with a default of 0

```
newdict = {x: dict1.get(x, 0) + dict2.get(x, 0) for x in set(dict1) | set(dict2)}
```

Comment: Nice answer - I'd prefer this union of keys to my approach of converting to lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the second dictionary checking if each key element is in the first dict, to decide whether values have to be summed or assigned:

```
dict1 = {
    "Elizabeth Alexandra Mary": 250000,
    "Barack Hussein Obama II": 1750000,
    "Zhang Aiqin": 1000,
    "Dean Craig Pelton": 1000000,
    }

dict2 = {
    "Christopher Larkin": 50000,
    "Eyal Shani": 5000,
    "Dean Craig Pelton": 2500000,
    "Sheldon Cooper": 15600000
    }

for i in dict2:
  if not i in dict1:
    dict1[i] = dict2[i]
  else:
    dict1[i] = dict1[i] + dict2[i]

print('Updated dictionary:')
print(dict1)
```

**Output:**

```
Updated dictionary:
{'Elizabeth Alexandra Mary': 250000, 'Barack Hussein Obama II': 1750000, 'Zhang Aiqin': 1000, 'Dean Craig Pelton': 3500000, 'Christopher Larkin': 50000, 'Eyal Shani': 5000, 'Sheldon Cooper': 15600000}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `defaultdict` might provide a more elegant solution than a regular dictionary. Here each value defaults to `0` if referenced before assignment.

```python3
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = defaultdict(int, {
    "Elizabeth Alexandra Mary": 250000,
    "Barack Hussein Obama II": 1750000,
    "Zhang Aiqin": 1000,
    "Dean Craig Pelton": 1000000,
})
dict2 = {
    "Christopher Larkin": 50000,
    "Eyal Shani": 5000,
    "Dean Craig Pelton": 2500000,
    "Sheldon Cooper": 15600000
}

for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict1[k] += v

print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu should be able to do it with a comprehension -

```py
combined = {k: dict1.get(k, 0) + dict2.get(k, 0) for k in list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys())}
```

**Output**

```
{'Elizabeth Alexandra Mary': 250000,
 'Barack Hussein Obama II': 1750000,
 'Zhang Aiqin': 1000,
 'Dean Craig Pelton': 3500000,
 'Christopher Larkin': 50000,
 'Eyal Shani': 5000,
 'Sheldon Cooper': 15600000}
```

Comment: the calls `.keys()` are redundant. Just `list(dict1) + list(dict2)`